# Children's Fantasy

Tags: riddle

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

> A room full of me would be a child's fantasy.
>
> Mini or large is what I can be,
>
> I am a pirate, a superhero, and a civilian, all at once.
>
> Make me fly or make me ride,
>
> Allow your imagination to take play.
>
> Foreign I may be,
>
> But you may find my land in your own land.
>
> You can even find me at a presidential center for show!
>
> So, take me into your own hands to witness what I am.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this may be a bit broad as I can think of a few but here's the one that struck me first:

> LEGO

A room full of me would be a child's fantasy.

> Me as a child anyway

Mini or large is what I can be,

> you can build big and small stuff, or maybe a reference to Micro-blox and Duplo

I am a pirate, a superhero, and a civilian, all at once.

> Lego men can be pirates and superheroes or a mix and match

Make me fly or make me ride,

> Airships and buggies

Allow your imagination to take play.

> Has anyone seen the LEGO movie?

Foreign I may be,

> I think it's like, Norwegian or something?

But you may find my land in your own land.

> There's a lego-land here in the UK

You can even find me at a presidential center on a show!

> Uncertain, but lots of places have lego miniature versions of themselves on display.

So, take me into your own hands to witness what I am.

> A toy you make stuff from

Comment: Yup that is it.

Comment: Oh, and I was referencing  the Kennedy(Previous president)  space center in North America.

Comment: Denmark, though.